# Raycast is detecting player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
playerLayer = 11; 

         if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, crooshair.transform.position - transform.position, 100, ~playerLayer);

        if (hit != null)
        {
            Interactable interactable = hit.collider.GetComponent<Interactable>();
            if (interactable != null)
            {
                SetFocus(interactable);
            }

        }
        else
            Debug.Log("Nothing was hit");
    }
```

Every time my player shoot a raycast it ends up hitting my player. The reason this is is because the raycast is starting inside of the player (which is what I want it to do) but it keeps detecting the player no matter what I do. I've used layers, tried to disable Queries start in colliders, and even starting the raycast from a little bit outside of the player but nothing works. When I try and offset the raycast from the player it sometimes works but that is only as long as you shoot in the direction that the offset is going. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Does your `Player` have any childed objects with a `Collider` that are not layered as `playerLayer`? Just to assure your layermask is setup correctly, I would advise assigning it in the inspector then invert it using the tilde.

```
public LayerMask playerLayer;

void Update()
 {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, crooshair.transform.position, 100, ~playerLayer);
        if (hit != null)
        {
            Interactable interactable = hit.collider.GetComponent<Interactable>();
            if (interactable != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("Hit" + hit.collider.name);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

If you are still unable to debug this with assigning the `LayerMask` in the inspector, if you could post your hierarchy it might help solve the issue.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I edited my post but you have to press the link because I don't have 10 reputation.

Comment: I didn't see that you made playerLayer a layer mask. I did that and now it's registering the player again.

Comment: @Jack_AKA_Oscar Are `GunRotation` and/or `gun_blue` colliders?

Comment: No. Gun rotation is an empty object and gun_blue is a sprite. Neither of which have colliders on them (nor rigidbodys).

Comment: @Jack_AKA_Oscar Either try without the tilde or try instead of placing `playerLayer`, do `playerLayer.value`.

Comment: What do you mean by,  "invert it using tilde"?

Comment: The symbol `~` is a tilde. It will invert a layer mask. It will flip what the mask does. So if you set it to hit a single layer, using a tilde will flip what it does or does not hit.

Comment: Oh yeah. I did that

Comment: I tried both of those things. If I do player.value it registers the player. If I do playerLayer it detects the player. If I do those both tilde it gives me the error, "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: I also get the warning, "warning CS0472: The result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'bool' is never equal to 'null' of type 'bool?'"

Comment: Something I did worked. When I hit anything besides the interactable my Debug.Log works and it says what my ray hit. But when I hit the interactable it gives me the error I said earlier. The line of code that it's mad with is,                                             
          Interactable interactable = hit.collider.GetComponent<Interactable>();

Comment: That's because you hit something that doesn't have the script intractable.

Comment: So using the `playerLayer` is the right answer and you get a null because you're hitting objects without the script

Comment: No. The one thing that I am getting the error for is the one thing that has the script attached. Every other thing I hit doesn't give me an error.

Comment: Just to be clear then, the error is thrown on the line of `GetComponent`? Or is thrown later when you try to access the intractable object you hit?

Comment: Are you destroying anything anywhere? It's saying the object you're trying trying to get the component of doesn't exist. You need to also check if the hit.collider is null or try hit.collider.gameObject

Comment: I'm not destroying it anywhere. It's not saying it's declared somewhere else and if I do hit.collider.gameObject it gives me the error, "The property 'Component.gameObject' cannot be used with type arguments.

Comment: Can you update the question with your current code? Or is it exactly the same?

Comment: I figured it out. The player finally detects the interactable but the error is still there if I don't hit anything. I updated my code as well.

Comment: You've also tried adding a hit.collider != null in the if statement? So `if(hit!= null && hit.collider != null)`